# Do I need PolylineOptions?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I got confused. Do I need PolylineOptions? When should I use it? I tried searching everywhere but can't seem to find the answer I need, even in the docs. What is the concrete difference or advantage when I use PolylineOptions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PolylineOptions is a "Builder" pattern for creating a Polyline. Since some elements are mandatory to create a polyline, while others can be optional (or have a default).
So the advantage of PolylineOptions is that you need it to create a polyline!
After you create a Polyline (adding it to the map and retrieving it in the response value of the method), you no longer need the polyline options you used, but you directly use the polyline.

Does this answer to your question? Do you need more info? I think that if you look at the examples on adding polylines, you get more clue of what you can do with it.

Answer (score 1):

PolyLine in google maps are used to drwa line over map.
Generally to add polyline in MAP,
we used  `map.addPolyline(polyLineOptions)` method it will return regrence to PolyLine Object.

And

> PolyLineOptions actually defines options for a polyline

.like adding points, seting color width etc.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you need PolylineOptions instance, when you want to draw some polyline on map. You can read [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolylineOptions) and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes) more about that.

**P.S.:** If your question was "why I need to draw polyline on the map", then answer is: for example, to draw some path to something. It depends a lot on your application. May be you make some map-game and you need to show path to treasure :)

Comment: I already read the docs. And nope, the question is do I need polyoptions to draw a path. Thank you.

Comment: As I answered in a first sentence, yes, you need it.